# Отлельное доменное имя в режиме мультисайт

Tags: wordpress

Есть сайт который создан через WP мультисайт. Как к нему привязать отдельный домен?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На странице [Управление сетью-сайты](http:///wp-admin/network/sites.php) создайте новый сайт и укажите его доменное имя. Затем на странице [редактирования сайта](http:///wp-admin/network/site-settings.php?id=2) (id=номер нового сайта) укажите Siteurl и Home. Все три поля должны выглядеть как http://mysite.ru